# Visual glitches while scrolling with vue-virtual-scroler and Vuetify 2.0 - not smooth visualization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Content doesn't render smoothly while scrolling on desktop (Chrome/Firefox) and mobile devices. Visual glitches appear even if you scroll very slowly. This happens with both DynamicScroller and RecycleScroller. In my case I have a list of 300 cards with variable height, approximately 180px each. The card is composed mostly of Vuetify 2.0 components `<v-row>, <v-col>, <v-flex>, <v-avatar>, <-v-chip>, <v-btn>`, etc., where most of them have `display: flex, justify-content, align-self` and other alignment CSS properties.

I ran several performance tests and the overall FPS drops drastically when scrolling. You can see it here -> [Vue Virtual Scroller - Performance Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygu6J.jpg)

I found out that each DynamicScrollerItem represents a layer (in Chrome Layers tool) which is positioned with the help of transform: 'translateY(number)'. Could this cause the issue? I tried various configurations with `min-item-size`, `buffer` and other props with no avail.

#### [**Demo Scroll Issue Here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/s-a-s-h-o/scroll-performance-issue)

Example: DynamicScroller pseudo configuration

```
 <template v-slot="{ item, index, active }">
  <DynamicScrollerItem :item="item" :active="active" :data-index="index">
    <v-card>
      <v-row>
        <!-- Card Content Here  --> 
      </v-row>
   </v-card>
  </DynamicScrollerItem>
 </template>
</DynamicScroller>
```

Any ideas are welcome and thank you for your attention!